# Is there a way to invoke the parent of a parent in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, theory

(Just a theoretical question, I don't see a direct practical use)

Is there a way to do something like:

```
super.super.someMethod()
```

In Java?

```
super.someMethod()
```

exists, why not be able to invoke the super class of a super class?

(of course you can create a method:

```
protected void someSuperMethod(){
    super.someMethod();
}
```

In the super class and invoke that in the child class having the same effect, but is there a direct way of doing that and, if not, why?)

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ugly workaround, but they should not be used as it is bad practice.

When you inherit from an object it is fine, but you should not be able to access directly the parent of this object as changing it behaviour might also change the behaviour of your first parent.

The workaround you proposed is fine, as it is a method that is defined in the parent itself, therefore it does not change the behaviour as the parent access it own parent itself instead of the child accessing it grand-parent bypassing it first parent.

This is mainly why there is no direct way of doing this. If you want to access something in the grand-parent, then it should be done in the first parent instead, and in your child you tell the parent to access it parent.

Suppose you define an Object of type A, B and C.

- B extends A, and C extends B.
- Both A and B have the same method, with different validation.
- Since C extends B, calling the method should use the validation of B, not A.
- Using super.super you could call directly the method in A and skip the validation of B which would break the inheritance security/rule.